# I can't load Spritsheet CreateJS in Cordova projects ( ISO 9 )

Tags: cordova, createjs, preloadjs

I use PreloadJs to load the SpritSheet:

```
manifestLoad: any[] = [
    { "src": "spriteSheet.json", 
      "id": "spriteSheet-json", 
      "type": createjs.AbstractLoader.SPRITESHEET
    }];
loadQueue.loadManifest(manifestLoad, true, Config.sPathGlobal);
```

For IOS APP we use the [cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) that implements the WKWebView component instead of the default UIWebView component.

However, you are still not able to use XHR from the file:// protocol.

I changed the parameter of LoadQueue to not use XHR, but some content requires XHR to work like JSON.

Comment: You may need to use JSONP to load JSON from the file:// protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by registering the plugin in localwebserver.

Today the application run at http://localhost instead of file://